# drag and drop and swap tiles in Grid view

Tags: java, android, android-gridview

I am preparing an application with Grid view with 2 row 2 column .

I am using Imageview and textview inside the Grid using ViewHolder to display the grid.
Image is stored as

```
            public Integer[] mThumbIds = 
           {
            R.drawable.add_deviceadd_normal, R.drawable.saw,
            R.drawable.see, R.drawable.seesaw               
            };
```

Now I want to achieve tile swtiching ( drag and drop and swapping of tiles).

When user click and drag , i need to swap the positions of the images inside the grid. action on Long Press.

I already use OnItem click function for a different purpose.

```
   mgridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.Favorite_GridView);
    customGridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, getData());
    mgridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);       
    mgridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
```

I need to achieve Drag and drop and swap position on Long press.

Please give some example on how to achieve darag and drop and swap images between the tiles in the grid

Comment: Checkout this library - https://github.com/askerov/DynamicGrid

Comment: here is example for drag and drop views, try to understand this: https://github.com/koduribalaji/AndroidCoolDragAndDropGridView

Comment: @balajikoduri and Ashish . Thank you for your support for the examples. From the code , i see that there are lot of classes used. My code is inside just 1 mainactivity and i use grid view and adapter inside the same activity class. I am confused about ur code as it has lot of classes. Please tell me how to re-write ur code to use it inside my activity. (adding listener and drag methods).